# Multiplying user's input values from column \"Shape_Leng\" using field calculator in PyQGIS for a QGIS Plugin?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I have trouble to calculate a new column as an output based on a simple calculation of user's various input multiply it with the length column of a polyline vector inputs.

I have created a plugin but the code does not want to work.
What I mean is that when I am trying to run the plugin, everything looks fine. I can select the layers i want to include as well as the Input values. But on the new column i get `NULL` values. I have tried to change the formula, and I am sure it recognizes the `shape_leng` but something goes wrong with the input values that are need to be multiplied, `@ConnectionPipesCostDKK` and `@DistributionPipesCostDKK`

I have tried to run the code in the console and works perfectly fine.
Any help?
This is the Code of `class FORSAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm)`:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Network', 'Distribution Pipes', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('ConnectionPipes', 'Connection Pipes', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('ConnectionPipesCostDKK', 'Connection Pipes Cost (DKK)', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=1e+06, defaultValue=2500))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('DistributionPipesCostDKK', 'Distribution Pipes Cost (DKK)', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=100000, defaultValue=4500))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes', 'New Calculated Cost Connection Pipes', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes', 'New Calculated Cost Distribution Pipes', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(2, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}

    # Connection Pipes
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'New Cost Connection Pipes',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
        'FORMULA': (" \"Shape_Leng\" * @ConnectionPipesCostDKK \r\n "),
        'INPUT': parameters['ConnectionPipes'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes']
    }
    outputs['ConnectionPipes'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes'] = outputs['ConnectionPipes']['OUTPUT']

    feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
    if feedback.isCanceled():
        return {}

    # Distribution Pipes
    alg_params = {
        'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
        'FIELD_NAME': 'New Cost Distribution Pipes',
        'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
        'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
        'FORMULA': ' \"Shape_Leng\" *  @DistributionPipesCostDKK \r\n ',
        'INPUT': parameters['Network'],
        'OUTPUT': parameters['NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes']
    }
    outputs['DistributionPipes'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    results['NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes'] = outputs['DistributionPipes']['OUTPUT']
    return results
```

Comment: Hi @MrXsquared   
Sure.  What i mean is that when i am trying to run the plugin. Everything looks fine. I can select the layers i want to include as well as the Input values. But on the new column i get "NULL" values. I have tried to change the formula, and I am sure it recognizes the \shape_leng\ but something goes wrong with the input values that are needed to be multiplied, "@ConnectionPipesCostDKK" and "@DistributionPipesCostDKK" .

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out why my script did not work as a plugin python script. Well, the Formulas that are typed above in the script, when it comes to plugins are read as strings. So, although the Formula is exported this way from the model builder can not be read by the plugin.  So the first thing I did was to create a variable of the Users Input and then change a bit a the formula. So, the script that works looks like this

class FORSAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('Network', 'Distribution Pipes', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('ConnectionPipes', 'Connection Pipes', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('DistributionPipesCostDKK', 'Distribution Pipes Cost (DKK)', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=100000, defaultValue=4500))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterNumber('ConnectionPipesCostDKK', 'Connection Pipes Cost (DKK)', type=QgsProcessingParameterNumber.Integer, minValue=0, maxValue=100000, defaultValue=2500))
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes', 'New Calculated Cost Connection Pipes', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes', 'New Calculated Cost Distribution Pipes', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))



            
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(13, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}
    param1 =str(parameters['ConnectionPipesCostDKK'])
    param2 =str(parameters['DistributionPipesCostDKK'])

# Connection Pipes
alg_params = {
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_NAME': 'New Cost Connection Pipes',
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
    'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
    'FORMULA': ' \"Shape_Leng\" *' +param1,
    'INPUT': parameters['ConnectionPipes'],
    'OUTPUT': parameters['NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes']
}
outputs['ConnectionPipes'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
results['NewCalculatedCostConnectionPipes'] = outputs['ConnectionPipes']['OUTPUT']

feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
if feedback.isCanceled():
    return {}

# Distribution Pipes
alg_params = {
    'FIELD_LENGTH': 10,
    'FIELD_NAME': 'New Cost Distribution Pipes',
    'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
    'FIELD_TYPE': 0,  # Float
    'FORMULA': ' \"Shape_Leng\" *' +param2,
    'INPUT': parameters['Network'],
    'OUTPUT': parameters['NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes']
}
outputs['DistributionPipes'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
results['NewCalculatedCostDistributionPipes'] = outputs['DistributionPipes']['OUTPUT']
return results
```

pyqgis
qgis-plugins
qgis-processing